# IIS cheat sheet

Tags: iis

Is there a cheat sheet for the different versions of IIS which details various steps to perfom for each new website deployment including compression, caching, AppPool settings. etc.

Edit:
I'm not looking for a list of things you must do, more of a list of the most common things you could do (like compression and caching etc).

Comment: I've not seen anything I'd trust, to be honest I've not looked that hard because I don't think it's a "one size fits all" thing; this is something where I'd expect an admin to draw up their own in concert with the developers when its a bespoke app.

Answer (score 1):

As both IIS 6 and IIS 7/7.5 has different interface to deal with. You can check though for me most common things in all versions from IIS 6 is following:

1) Extension need to be enabled
2) Application pool Settings
3) Permission on folders 
4) Host Header or Bindings
5) Mime Types

Please let me know if this would helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

I don;t think here has one but this old one(http://blogs.iis.net/blogs/sivas/IIS_Version_Comparison_Chart.jpg) compared iis5 and 6. Too bad, no iis7 on this chart.

Answer (score -1):

I have made an attempt of writing a [Did you know](http://www.dotnetscraps.com/dotnetscraps/category/Did-you-know.aspx) series which shows steps by steps on how to configure settings in IIS 6 and IIS 7.

Comment: Link redirects to survey..